# Linux extract values from bash scipt

Tags: bash, shell, init

I'm trying to write a bash script, but there is a problem - I can't see the variable's content outside of do-done. Any help?

```
#!/bin/bash

file="ip.txt"

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
     printf '%s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
done <"$file"

printf '%s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"

echo -e "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $f2 -j DNAT --to-destination $f1:$f3"
```

Output>

```
192.168.0.1  
2000  
1000  

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport  -j DNAT --to-destination :
```

Comment: Can you check your output? I think the 3 values `192.168.0.1 2000 1000` are on one line.

Comment: `read` assigns each variable to the empty string on the final read.  That empty value is entirely visible to your script!  (Just not particularly useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your problem with

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3
do
     printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
done <<< "192.168.0.1:2000:1000"
printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
```

You made a construction where you can use the vars that were set in the loop, but not the the vars set by read.
You can use

```
while IFS=: read -r xf1 xf2 xf3
do
     printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$xf1" "$xf2" "$xf3"
     f1=$xf1
     f2=$xf2
     f3=$xf3
done <<< "192.168.0.1:2000:1000"
printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
```

I guess you do not want to use this one, so read the line inside the loop:

```
while read -r line
do
     IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 <<< "${line}"
     printf 'Loop: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
done <<< "192.168.0.1:2000:1000"
printf 'After: %s %s %s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the problem that you have an empty line at the end of your file, and thus $f1 $f2 $f3 becomes empty at the final iteration of the loop?

Comment: Shouldn't be in this case **two** empty output lines between *1000* and *iptables....*? The first empty output line would be from the `printf` inside the loop, where the supposedly empty input line is read, and the second would be from the `printf` after the loop.

Comment: @voyvoda: To verify the idea brought up by JohanThomsen, change your `printf` inside the loop to something like `printf 'f1=%s f2=%s f3=%s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"`, so that you can better see when you have empty input

Answer (score 0):

Its known bash behaviour. Read here, why and how to avoid: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_- or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: These links apply to a different scenario from the one in the question.  Those describe the `cmd | while read …` stuff; that doesn't apply here.

Comment: I stay corrected, didn't look carefully enough. Looks similar in the result, but  has a different root cause.